# Why doesn't rectangle.setOnDragEntered(..) work for me?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

Using JavaFX, the statements

```
rectangle.setOnMousePressed(e -> System.out.println("Mouse pressed"));
```

and

```
 rectangle.setOnMouseReleased(e -> System.out.println("Mouse released"));
```

work fine. However

```
rectangle.setOnMouseDragEntered(e -> System.out.println("Drag entered"));
```

and

```
rectangle.setOnDragEntered(e -> System.out.println("Drag entered"));
```

don't seem to do anything at all. What am I doing wrong or are these methods simply not implemented?

Comment: You need to provide more complete information about what you have done and the conditions under which the drag is occurring. Have you read the [documentation on dragging gestures](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html)?

Comment: I have a piano key and I want the key to play when the mouse is over the key and left click is down regardless of the initial position of the left click.

Comment: Very nice. You need to provide more complete information about what you have done and the conditions under which the drag is occurring. Have you read the [documentation on dragging gestures](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html)?

Comment: Yes. Even with rectangle.setOnDragDetected(e -> rectangle.startFullDrag()); it's not working.

Comment: Works fine for me. [Edit] your question to include a [MCVE].

Comment: Yep works now. Thanks a lot :)